# boost dynamic_bitset copy bits from uint16

Tags: c++, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset

I need to create 24 bit set.
First (0) bit have to be set by bool.
And other (1 - 23) I need to copy first bits from uint32 value

Is it possible to do it with dynamic_bitset ?

My code I tried but wrong:

```
typedef boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> DataType;
DataType bs(24, intValue);
bs.set(0, booleanValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just left-shift:

```
    DataType bs(24, intValue);
    bs <<= 1;
    bs.set(0, boolValue);
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c04ac88b05dd1f33)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <iostream>
typedef boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> DataType;

int main() {
    using namespace std; // for readability on SO
    cout << hex << showbase;

    uint32_t intValue = 0x666;
    cout << "input: " << intValue;

    DataType bs(24, intValue);

    cout << "\n#1: " << bs << " " << bs.to_ulong();

    bs <<= 1;
    cout << "\n#2: " << bs << " " << bs.to_ulong();

    bs.set(0, true);

    cout << "\n#3: " << bs << " " << bs.to_ulong();
}
```

Prints:

```
input: 0x666
#1: 000000000000011001100110 0x666
#2: 000000000000110011001100 0xccc
#3: 000000000000110011001101 0xccd
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting. But this code will replace 0th bit of int value in bitset with boolean.

Comment: Updated after re-reading the edited question. [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c04ac88b05dd1f33)

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to do it in this way, without boost bitset:

```
uint32_t buffer(0xAAAAAAAA);
buffer = buffer << 1;
buffer |= true << 0;

unsigned char newRecord[3];

newRecord[0] = buffer;
newRecord[1] = buffer << 8;
newRecord[2] = buffer << 16;
```

Comment: `true << 0` - what is that trying to achieve